# How to allow cross domain access in elasticsearch 2.0.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-2.0

Im, Trying to enable cross domain access in elasticsearch 2.0.0.
The following is output configuration in logstash 2.0.0 :

```
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  } 
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    header => {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "true"}
    index => "testindex"
  }
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Expected one of #, => at line 28, column 42 (byte 500) after output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        header => {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks

PS: I think this is most likely a syntax error cause when I remove the header from output everything else works fine.

Comment: Solved It. I added the following in elasticsearch.yml
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.allow-headers: "x-csrf-token, x-requested-with"
http.cors.enabled: true

Answer (score 0):

You can try using * or the actual domain name from where you are making the request.

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" or

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://yourdomain.com"

refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Tried this. However Im getting the same error. I think theres some sort of syntax error, because everything else works fine if i remove the header line from output.